# Can't import installed custom module through python shell, but working fine with ipython/jupyter

Tags: python, python-module

I've just sucessfully installed my module, let's call it `MyModule` with the following command

```
python setup.py install
```

then I wanted to call it through a command with something like

```
python -m MyModule
```

But I get this error

```
/Users/.../miniconda3/envs/py36/bin/python: No module named MyModule
```

Do you know whats going on ?

**EDIT** : I can't import it through python shell, but it is working with ipython and jupyter notebook ...

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct python version? (E.g. Python instead of Python3)?

Comment: I did all these actions after "source activate py36" (Python 3.6)